# Unable to convert java.sql.Timestamp to com.google.cloud.Timestamp in Spring Data Cloud Spanner

Tags: java, google-cloud-spanner

While using Spring Data Cloud Spanner, we are unable to persist java.sql.Timestamp type data in spanner db. The database column type is Timestamp.

Following is the entity:

```
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class Test {
  
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(name = “ID”)
  private String id;
 
  @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
  private java.sql.Timestamp createdOn;

}
```

We are using Spring Data Rest to persist.

As per my analysis, I see a converter is already there which converts java.sql.TimeStamp to com.google.cloud.Timestamp.

```
public static final Converter<java.sql.Timestamp, Timestamp> JAVA_TO_SPANNER_TIMESTAMP_CONVERTER =
                    new Converter<java.sql.Timestamp, Timestamp>() {
                        // @formatter:on
                        @Nullable
                        @Override
                        public Timestamp convert(java.sql.Timestamp timestamp) {
                            return Timestamp.of(timestamp);
                        }
                    };

    /**
     * A converter from the Spanner instantaneous time type to {@link java.sql.Timestamp}.
     */
    // @formatter:off
    public static final Converter<Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp> SPANNER_TO_JAVA_TIMESTAMP_CONVERTER =
                    new Converter<Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp>() {
                        // @formatter:on
                        @Nullable
                        @Override
                        public java.sql.Timestamp convert(Timestamp timestamp) {
                            return java.sql.Timestamp.from(TIMESTAMP_INSTANT_CONVERTER.convert(timestamp));
                        }
                    };
```

Instead of that while searching for perfect match from source type to target type, it is getting a perfect match between java.sql.Timestamp to com.google.cloud.Date because of this following code snippet.

```
public GenericConverter find(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
            // Search the full type hierarchy
            List<Class<?>> sourceCandidates = getClassHierarchy(sourceType.getType());
            List<Class<?>> targetCandidates = getClassHierarchy(targetType.getType());
            for (Class<?> sourceCandidate : sourceCandidates) {
                for (Class<?> targetCandidate : targetCandidates) {
                    ConvertiblePair convertiblePair = new ConvertiblePair(sourceCandidate, targetCandidate);
                    GenericConverter converter = getRegisteredConverter(sourceType, targetType, convertiblePair);
                    if (converter != null) {
                        return converter;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This method returns a converter for source type java.sql.Timestamp which is actually responsible for converting java.util.Date to com.google.cloud.Date as java.util.Date is super class of java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: Hi @ayancancode, I am with the Cloud Spanner team, and we are currently looking at this particular issue. Please stay tuned.

Comment: @fuad-malikov This issue is for java.util.Date and java.sql.Timestamp. I see all the spanner unit tests pass if we omit these two scenarios. As they have inheritance between them, we are facing this issue. Please check my comment on the pull request raised for this fix already.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in this PR https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/pull/2065 and the fix is available in 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Can you please try and give us a feedback.

Thanks,

Comment: The fix was also applied to the 1.2.x branch, which is scheduled to be released on December 18th as version 1.2.1.